# how to redirect url after submitting a form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

It seems to be a simple but still it is difficult for me to achieve.
Let`s make a small example to clarify the situation: 
There are two files: **Form.PHP** and **Action.PHP**

**Form.PHP** has one Input field with name = "ID"
and button SUBMIT

Action.PHP has a script of inserting data in MySQL
and in the end next line:

```
header("location:Form.PHP");
```

So after the submitting the form, I come back to Form.PHP...
This is easy...

Now, I want to achieve - after the submitting the form redirection to
**Form.PHP?ID=$_POST['ID']**

So please help me to modify 
**header("location:Form.PHP");** to redirect to **?ID=$_POST['ID']**

Comment: Why u use PHP as extension ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
header("Location: Form.PHP?ID=".$_POST['ID']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header("location:Form.PHP?ID=" . $_POST['ID']);
```

Comment: `$_POST['ID']` may not be inside those double quotes

Answer (score 1):

It's usual URL writing like we normally do. Your code would be

`header("location:form.php?id=$id");`

make sure you initialize `$id = $_POS['id'];`

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Location: Form.PHP?ID=".$ID);
```

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to use `extract` here? There's a huge warning in the documentation